# Next.js + React Query (data is undefined)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

This is the first time to use React Query with Next.

My problem is this, I am trying to make a query with useQuery, but the result of my "data", which I called "response" is undefined.

I don't understand why I'm making an error, because the code I have is basically what I have done so far.

My app.js code:

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Hydrate>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </>
  )
}
```

My threads.js code:

```
const { data: response } = useQuery(['threads', { token: stateToken }], QueryThreads)
console.log(response.data)
```

I hope you have a great day!

Comment: can you try and see what you get doing this: const { data} = useQuery(['threads', { token: stateToken }], QueryThreads)
console.log(data)

Comment: @Sir Codes Alot  says that data is undefined

Comment: const { isLoading,error,data} = useQuery(['threads', { token: stateToken }], QueryThreads)
if(isLoading) return "Loading...";
if(error) return "Error...:;
console.log(response.data)

If that doesn't work, can you put an example up on https://codesandbox.io/ to troubleshoot

Comment: @Sir Codes Alot Thanks! It works! I just needed to use isLoading and isError!

Comment: have you done this const queryClient = new QueryClient(); at the `_app.js`?

Answer (score 1):

React Query supports two ways of prefetching data

1. using 'initialData'
2. using hydration method

As you have used hydration method you can use getServerSideProps() to prefetch data.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {

  const queryClient =new QueryClient();
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery (['threads', { token: stateToken }], QueryThreads)

  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
    },
  }
}
```

Refer [React Query docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/ssr#using-hydration).